CodeQl : could not resolve module python problem
I am trying to run a simple code ql command on my vscode. but when i try to execute this program:
import python

from File f
where f.getFileExtension() = "py"
select f, "Fichier Python analysé"


there is an error indicating this :
Failed to run query: 
ERROR: could not resolve module python (H:\Desktop\Codeql\test.ql:1,8-14) 
ERROR: could not resolve type File (H:\Desktop\Codeql\test.ql:3,6-10

I dowloaded the database before executing the query with this command :
codeql database create database --language=python --overwrite     

My codeql runs well when I type codeql --version:
PS H:\Desktop\Codeql> codeql --version                                                                                       
CodeQL command-line toolchain release 2.19.3.
Copyright (C) 2019-2024 GitHub, Inc.
Unpacked in: h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql
   Analysis results depend critically on separately distributed query and
   extractor modules. To list modules that are visible to the toolchain,
   use 'codeql resolve packs' and 'codeql resolve languages'.
PS H:\Desktop\Codeql> codeql resolve languages
cpp (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\cpp)
csharp (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\csharp)
csv (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\csv)
go (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\go)
html (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\html)
java (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\java)
javascript (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\javascript)
properties (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\properties)
python (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\python)
ruby (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\ruby)
swift (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\swift)
xml (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\xml)
yaml (h:\Desktop\codeql-win64\codeql\yaml)

I don't know how to solve the problem.
I am expecting this program to run correctly, I have installed and uninstalled codeql on this site, downloading the codeql-wi64 version. I added the paths correctly ( I am using windows but even on my linux it doesn't work )
